# Lenovo E15 Gen 2 (AMD Ryzen 5 4500U) CPU upgrade options

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen

What options do I have for looking at CPU upgrades for a `Lenovo E15 Gen 2` with an `AMD Ryzen 5 4500U`?

I'd like to know perhaps what AMD CPU line I should be researching.

Comment: You have no options. And hardware recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: It was not 100% clear, but the article and video I saw suggested the CPU is soldered in.

Comment: Is there a Stack Exchange site for computer hardware?

Comment: While it might be possible, the correct answer for 99.9% of all users indeed is "no option, not possible". If you have industrial resolder capability then that is not correct, but for almost all end users the upgrade path is 'buy a new laptop', or 'buy a new laptop with a socketed CPU' (which will not lead you to most consumer laptops, though it might be relevant for portable workstations or high end gaming laptops.